# Devexpress DropDownList causing chrome to crash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, devexpress

I have a dropdownlist bound to 3300 items. When i use IE it all works fine, but on chrome i get a big "he's dead Jim"... the crash happens if i "open the dropbox" and do any other action (such as press `esc`, or click outside it)... how can i work around this?!? is there any optimization i can do?!?

heres the partial for my drop:

```
@Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(s =>
        {
            s.Name = "PlanoContasId";
            s.Width = 400;
            s.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.Contains;
            s.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDown;
            s.Properties.TextField = "Code";
            s.Properties.ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
            s.Properties.NullDisplayText = " ";
            s.Properties.ValueField = "PlanoContasId";
            s.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);                
            s.ShowModelErrors = true;                         
            s.Properties.ValidationSettings.ErrorDisplayMode = ErrorDisplayMode.None;
            s.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0} - {1}";
            s.Properties.Columns.Add("Code", "Code", 100);
            s.Properties.Columns.Add("Description", "Description", 255);                
        }).BindList(PlanoContasHelper.GetPlanoContasRange, PlanoContasHelper.GetPlanoContasByID).Bind(Model.PlanoContasId).GetHtml()
```

**Edit 1**
IE dev tools shows a MASSIVE cpu usage and resource consumption when I open the dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a terrible thing... I ended up having to customize loading since Chrome completed crashed (IE did not crash the page, but lagged it out til completion...)

Pls take note that this component CANNOT handle "Regardless of dataset size" as ads suggest.
PS: This was tested in a 3gHz 4th Gen i5 with 8gb of available ram

Answer (score 0):

Get a look here, https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/ASPxGridLookup/FilterServerMode.aspx

i think that is a better choise than a combobox for your number of items and that load only the visible row